# media query is not working with viewport initial-scale 0.25

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
.navPosFixed{position:inherit !important; border:red solid 1px;}

}
```

Viewport

```
<script>
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i) 
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) 
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) 
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) 
        || navigator.userAgent.match(/iemobile/i)) { 
        document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=0.25" />'); 
        }
</script>
```

While the page has initial-scale 1.0 it works just fine, but once it is changed to 0.25, it simply ignores the media query.
I want to make page zoom out and want to run media queries for mobile device.

Comment: Surely making the page "zoom out" and "run media queries" is counter intuitive?

Comment: Is there any solution ?

Comment: Have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1"/>` and make your media queries work with that. I don't understand why you want to zoom the page out and have media queries at the same time?

Comment: Reason behind using zoom out is we have several pages that we cant make responsive for mobile as we used % width for all the grids to make it fluid. So in mobile it breaks the layout. i want to use media query to overwrite a css property in order to fix a issue.

Comment: Sounds incredibly convoluted in all honesty

Answer (score 0):

Once initial-scale is set to 0.25, the viewport width is equal to 480/0.25=1920.
So modify you css code as the below:

`@media screen and (max-width: 1920px){
.navPosFixed{position:inherit !important; border:red solid 1px;}
}`

By the way, some android browsers do not work when the initial-scale is not equal to 1.